# Convert string to float in Python

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have a csv file and I am trying to plot some of the contents and need to convert the strings to floats. My problem is the following:

When I run the code below,

```
with open('meteors.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:    
        print row[6]
```

I get this output:

```
58.58333
```

When I instead try

```
print type(row[6])
```

I get this output:

```
<type 'str'>
```

But when I try

```
 print float(row[6])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: coordinate_1
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is there some form of terminator on the end of the `string` such as `\n`, `\t` etc...?

Comment: not sure. Is there a way to check?

Comment: I reckon there probably is but I'm not sure of it sorry. Maybe @jamylak can help, he seems to have a clue about most python stuff

Comment: @TheMerovingian not when you use `csv` module and also the `int()`, `float()`, etc, functions ignore leading/trailing whitespace

Comment: @jamylak: But how do you take a `string` stored in a variable and print it out raw? like `r"string\n"` but with a variable instead of a literal

Comment: @TheMerovingian You mean like `repr(s)`

Comment: @user1571767: There you go, try `print(repr(row[6]))` and it should print out the raw `string` showing all terminating characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are seeing the first row, which has the column headers on your CSV file, and `coordinate_1` is a header.

You can either skip the first row:

```
with open('meteors.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next() # skips the first (header) row
    for row in reader:    
        print row[6]
```

Or, use [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), like this:

```
with open('meteors.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:    
        print row['coordinate_1']
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid you should also use `next()` function instead for the reason I specified on the other answer. Otherwise yes this is the cleaner way

Answer (score 2):

Your CSV file probably has a header that lists the name of each column. You can't convert those names into `float`s, so that's where your error is coming from.

You have to consume the header first:

```
with open('meteors.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    header = next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        print float(row[6])
```

Comment: yes because they change `.next` to the special method `.__next__`, since the function `next` was supposed to be used when it was created

Comment: @jamylak: Ah, I never knew that. Thanks.